# Onclick event doesn't handle in Chrome, but work fine in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have hand-made autocomplete ajax form, and here is code. Field with id "city" handles city and suggest cities starting with value of input form

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var input_field = $("#city");
    $("#city").keypress(function () {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var city_name = input_field.val()
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "<%=cities_autocomplete_path%>",
                data: {city_start_with:city_name}
            }).success(function (data) {
                $("#city_results").empty();
                if (data.length==0)
                    $("#city_results").hide();
                else
                {
                    $("#city_results").show()

                    for(var idx in data)
                        $("#city_results").append('<li onclick="alert(23123123);return false;" class="city_result" id="city_result_123"><span><a >test</a></span></li>');

                }
            });
        },500);
    })

});
```

Problem is that onclick event doesn't work in Chrome, but works fine in Firefox and Opera:

```
 $("#city_results").append('<li onclick="alert(23123123);return false;" class="city_result" id="city_result_123"><span><a >test</a></span></li>');
```

Anybody had same problems?

Comment: Did you check the console for errors, there's no reason that shouldn't work in Chrome, even if it's a horrible practice to append strings with inline javascript event handlers.

Comment: Yes, console is clean.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the best way to "inject" javascript like that with append.
After you've appended the li-element, you could bind the onclick-event afterwards.

Comment: $("#city_results li").on('click',function () { alert("something clicked") }); causes same problem

Comment: @VoldemarDuletskiy How about $("#city_results").on('click', 'li', function () { alert("something clicked") });

Comment: same problem, it doesn't handle

Comment: Try changing for(var idx in data) to regular for-loop for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ...

Comment: I have changed, the same situation. I also tried "live" function for all child "li" tags of "city_results", clicks hadneles only in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

try quote the text inside alert()

```
 $("#city_results").append('<li onclick="alert('23123123');return false;" class="city_result" id="city_result_123"><span><a >test</a></span></li>');
```